# Microsoft Face API [find similar] api key error

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, face-api

So I'm trying to follow The microsoft face api documentation [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395237) for the "FindSimilar" feature. There is an example at the bottom of the page where I use this code:

```
########### Python 3.2 #############
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
# Request headers
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{api key}',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/face/v1.0/findsimilars?%s" % params, "{body}", 
headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

I'm getting an error where it tells me my subscription key is invalid, but I checked my azure account status and I see no issues:

```
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t{"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}\n                \t\t'
```

Comment: Have you remove your API key or you just use `{api key}` as your key?

Comment: @TwistedSim use my real api key when I run it, yes sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0):

> Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key.

It indicates that `Invalid subscription Key or user/plan is blocked`. I recommand that you could [check the APi Key](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/).

```
headers = {
# Request headers
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '3c658abc64b348c1a5...',
}
```

[image]

Comment: I followed this exactly as you have it pictured and I still get the same error. Even if I use a NEW api key. I checked my azure portal as well as the link you show and it says the subscription is active. I'm not sure what to do